# How to get data by using CoreData model?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to get data by using core data,but something wrong happen.Here's the picture of my data model:
[image: data model]
And code of Feed.h

```
@interface Feed (CoreDataProperties)

@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *rssURL;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *summary;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSSet *feedItems;

@end
```

Firstly,I'm sure I get the data of Feed Table in My FeedList TableViewController.When I tap one row of the table,it should push to the FeedItem TableViewController which contains the data of FeedItem.Here's the code of First Controller:

```
- (void)cellDidPress:(NSIndexPath *)atIndexPath{
    if (atIndexPath.row < self.allFeeds.count) {
        RSFeedItemsViewController *itemsVC = [[RSFeedItemsViewController alloc] init];

        itemsVC.feed = self.allFeeds[atIndexPath.row];


        [self.navigationController pushViewController:itemsVC animated:YES];

    }
}
```

I try to get the FeedItem in my FeedItemsViewController

```
NSMutableArray *allItems = [[[self.feed feedItems] allObjects] mutableCopy];
```

And I'm getting the following exception:

```
 po [self.feed feedItems]
<FeedItem: 0x7fe95a484540> (entity: FeedItem; id: 0xd000000007f40002 <x-coredata://918D3499-5129-4D78-8F37-3D8D478FE482/FeedItem/p509> ; data: <fault>)

2016-07-10 14:17:33.176 RSFeedReader[98980:14910776] -[FeedItem allObjects]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe95a484540
```

Should I execute another fetch request to get the data of FeedItem?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you calling `allObjects` on a `FeedItem`?  What are you trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: @Avi FeedItem is a NSSet.I want to assign to a NSMutableArray

Comment: are you trying to get the all feedItems right? self.feed  is what type (NSMutableArray)

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P Yes,I want to get the feedItem which correspond with the Feed.

Comment: You _think_ it's an `NSSet`, but you're incorrect.  It's an `NSManagedObject` subclass.  Based on the model you included, you have a 1-1 relationship, but you're thinking you have a 1-many or many-many.

Comment: @Avi So I should change the relationship between to two model?

Comment: Based on the names and the code, I would say yes.  I don't know any more about your app or model than what you've posted, though.

Comment: @Avi I think you're right.Let me have a try.